# iPhone - Multithreading in Tableview - feasible approach?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uitableview, cocoa-touch, reloaddata

I have been tracking a nasty bug recently of which I knew it was occurring due to my multithreaded approach (I add the crashreport at the end).

In my App I load a UITableView and fill it with data I store using Coredata. This data in turn I retrieve from a webservice, thus it might take some time, depending on my connection.

Anyway, I have managed to track it down a little and I know the issue is because an array is empty though I thought it shouldn't be. Then, when

```
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is called the program crashes - but only sometimes!!!

I was wondering how to debug this properly and my approach was to call

```
reloadData
```

on the tableView after the view finishes loading. But appearantly

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

but of course this didn't help. Is the correct way here to create another thread and have it check repeatadly whether the data is ready and prepared? Any suggestions/opinions?

```
2011-01-19 21:50:49.605 myApp[2017:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception         
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x314d0987 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x319a149d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   CoreFoundation                      0x31462795 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 184 
3   myApp                                 0x000092f7 -[MyTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] + 106
4   UIKit                               0x33902bcf -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1338
5   UIKit                               0x33903529 -[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _ensureSectionOffsetIsValidForSection:] + 120
6   UIKit                               0x33902645 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 96
7   UIKit                               0x3390207b -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 82
8   UIKit                               0x33901bff -[UITableView reloadData] + 582
9   UIKit                               0x33904a0b -[UITableView _reloadDataIfNeeded] + 50
10  UIKit                               0x33904e63 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 18
11  UIKit                               0x338b10cf -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 26
12  CoreFoundation                      0x3146ebbf -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 22
13  QuartzCore                          0x30a6c685 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 120
14  QuartzCore                          0x30a6c43d CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 184
15  QuartzCore                          0x30a6656d _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 212
16  QuartzCore                          0x30a66383 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 190
17  QuartzCore                          0x30a70e4f _ZN2CA11Transaction5flushEv + 46
18  QuartzCore                          0x30a6db75 +[CATransaction flush] + 24
19  UIKit                               0x338e803f -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 30
20  UIKit                               0x338d6317 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 462
21  UIKit                               0x338a248b -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1114
22  UIKit                               0x338a1ec9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 44
23  UIKit                               0x338a1907 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
24  GraphicsServices                    0x35d66f03 PurpleEventCallback + 666
25  CoreFoundation                      0x314656ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
26  CoreFoundation                      0x314656c3 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
27  CoreFoundation                      0x31457f7d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
28  CoreFoundation                      0x31457c87 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
29  CoreFoundation                      0x31457b8f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
30  UIKit                               0x338d5309 -[UIApplication _run] + 380
31  UIKit                               0x338d2e93 UIApplicationMain + 670
32  myApp                               0x000029bf main + 70
33  myApp                               0x00002974 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

numberOfRows looks like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSLog(@"number of rows in section");
if (section == mySection) {

    return  [[articleArrays objectAtIndex:section] count];  

} else {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe here your process that performs the download, or more precisely an event callback should be the only place calling reload data. calling it after adding new data to the table dataSet.

returning a 0 in numberOfRowsInSection does not cause a crash but if you are trying to get a nested array when the count is 0, this will crash. Post your `numberOfRowsInSection` method for us to gawk at.

**EDIT:**

Sounds/Looks like background thread is mutating the array while its trying to do an object count.

user210504 is right in saying that synchronising the array is likely stop this.

Typically you would sync writes and therefore preventing `numberOfRowsInSection` from counting if your background thread is mutating it.  eg:

```
-(void)downloadFinished{

NSMutableArray * array  = [[NSArray alloc] init];//t
id * obj;//obj is your row data object.

@synchronized(ar)
{
    [array addObject:obj];//ar is your dataSet
}

[array release];
}
```

Comment: I added that. The funny thing is, as mentioned above, this happens randomly, as if he sometimes manages to do this fast enough.

Comment: Well, I did fix this, but somehow differently. Though I'd like to know, why @synchronized(articleArrays) didn't work for me. Anyway I think your approach is correct so thanks for guiding me that way!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is to encapsulate accesses to the Mutable Array in @synchronized block. This way you will be sure that you are not accessing the datastructure half way through. And then I also agree with what Luke just mentioned.

Comment: Could u elaborate the first part a little more?